# Awk timestamp greater than

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file which I'm trying to print only the lines with a timestamp greater than or equal to 22:01, but I cant seem to get it to work correctly.  As can be seen below it still prints the 8:05 timestamps as well?  Probably a school boy error but I'm struggling to get this working so any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
 cat /tmp/m1.out | awk '$1>="22:01"' 

    22:05:42:710
    23:05:42:710
    8:05:42:710
    8:05:42:710
    8:05:42:710
    8:05:42:710
    8:05:42:710
```

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: You are using "22:01" so I think it is a string comparison and then, '8' is greater than '22'.

Comment: Zeropad the hour field and try again.

Comment: @fernand0 - make it an answer! (And explain how to get the comparison right.)

Comment: Sorry, not enough time to try to reproduce it in order to help with the solution. Partial help is better than no help.

Comment: Just use sane timestamps!

Comment: There aren't too many hours after 10pm, so just `grep -E "^(22|23)" yourFile` should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been correctly identified in the comments. You are comparing against a string, which triggers a string comparison. In string comparison, "8:05:42:710" is greater than "22:01" because the first character "8" is greater than "2".

One option would be to split the time into the separate components and use numerical comparisons instead:

```
awk -F: '$1 >= 22 && $2 >= 1' /tmp/m1.out
```

If your logic is more complex, e.g. your file has more fields and you don't want to change the field separator, you can use `split`:

```
awk '{ split($1, pieces, /:/) } pieces[1] >= 22 && pieces[2] >= 1' file
```

Padding the field with a leading zero is a little more tricky and isn't necessary in your example, as a time with only one digit in the hours will never be greater than 22.

The best thing to do if possible would be to use a timestamp that is compatible with string comparison, although that would require control of whatever is producing the file you're working with.